# Java cambiar color a JButton Mac OS X

Tags: java

Estoy insertando el siguiente botón en un `JPanel` de la siguiente manera:

```
JButton button = new JButton();
button.setBounds(50, 50, 40, 40);
button.setBackground(Color.RED);
button.setOpaque(true);
this.add(button);
```

Añadir que tengo el layout del `JPanel` como `null`, para así jugar con las posiciones y el tamaño del botón (por eso tengo que poner a `true`el `setOpaque()`, si no, no se ve el color):

```
this.setLayout(null);
```

El problema es que el resultado no es el esperado, no se me pinta el botón, sino un contorno exterior como se puede apreciar en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De qué forma tengo que hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Le tienes algún icono al botón?, si no te recomiendo poner un texto al botón a ver que esta pasando, y dejar el código completo de tu ventana.

Comment: No le tengo ningún icono, cambiándole el tema visual sí funciona, por lo que no será error de código. Debe haber una manera de conseguirlo sin cambiarle el tema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por alguna extraña razón el tema 'Aqua Look & Feel' de Java para OS X no deja hacer esto posible por lo menos de manera mas fácil.
Alguna vez opté por cambiar el tema visual y entonces si. por ejemplo:

```
try {
  javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel( "javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel" );
} catch( Exception e ) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

... y boom:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues sí, de esa manera se soluciona, aunque estaría ideal conseguirlo sin cambiar el tema visual.

Comment: Seguro, sin cambiar el LAF es: `UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put( "Button.background", Color.RED );`